# Is floating-point multiplication commutative?

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, multiplication

Floating point numbers are not exact due to its limited precision. My question is: is multiplication commutative in floating number computer calculation?

For example

```
double a = ..;
double b = ...;
double c = a * b;
double d = b * a;
if (c == d)
   cout << "Yes, great floating";
```

Comment: Do you mean "is floating point multiplication commutative?"? If so, this may be relevant: [Is multiplication always commutative in inexact floating point arithmetic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5007400/953482)

Comment: If both `a` and `b` are NaN, you wouldn't necessarily get the same NaN if you switch the operands (but that's a pretty weird thing to rely on)

Comment: @harold And anyway, if the result is `NaN` then `a * b` and `b * a` will compare unequal even if the two results have the same representation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), yes, float multiplication is commutative.

> While floating-point addition and multiplication are both commutative (a + b = b + a and a×b = b×a), they are not necessarily associative. That is, (a + b) + c is not necessarily equal to a + (b + c).