# For 2 numbers only, is floating point addition and multiplication associative?

Tags: floating-point, addition, ieee-754

According to [Is Floating point addition and multiplication associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative), I know A+B+C would have different results with A+C+B because the result of (A+B)+C and (A+C)+B is different.

But how about if there are 2 numbers only? Does A+B have the same result as B+A?

Answer (score 3):

First, the question if A+B gives the same result as B+A is not about [*associativity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), but [*commutativity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). To answer your question, we need to know if the order of the operands for floating point addition and multiplication influences the result (as opposed to different groupings for the *associativity* question).

Now, IEEE-754 floating point addition and multiplication **are commutative** (but **not associative**, as you correctly pointed out in your question).

I should probably put an asterisk here, as different NaN's (actually, their so-called payloads) which are a part of IEEE-754 can violate commutativity, but I don't think you are interested in this particular case.

There is also [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007400/is-multiplication-always-commutative-in-inexact-floating-point-arithmetic) that actually answers the question of commutativity for floating-point operations – but I think that the confusion between the *commutativity* and *associativity* might be addressed for this question better.